# CSS centering an element in viewport vertically and horizontally and make it responsive Cross Browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

css to make div center horizontally and vertically

```
.centerd-element
{
    top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:150;
    /*max-width and max-height should be dynamic*/
    max-width:500px;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

This is working fine in all major browsers except ie8, in ie8 the element is stucked to the top of the viewport.

how can i make it work in ie8.

Comment: Have you tried one of the solutions proposed here: http://howtocenterincss.com/ ?

Comment: How can max-widths be dynamic? Do you mean the width should be dynamic but limited?

Comment: @Paulie_D basically max-width and max-height should be inline and set by javascript, but i can not use javascript to align the element.

Comment: @pinturic the element should be absolutely positioned with respect to its parent, in my case parent element is body.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on all browsers:

```
.centerd-element {
    position:absolute;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:black;

    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    height:200px;
    width:500px;
    margin:-100px -250px;
}
```

Comment: This is a hard value size...I believe the OP wanted dynamic widths.

Comment: I missed that... but I don't think it's possible cross-browser.  I hope someone proves me wrong

Comment: width and height should be dynamic